# Give an integer value to a macro through AC_DEFINE

Tags: c, macros, autotools, autoconf

One of my application has a `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` constant (the name of which is quite self-explanatory). This constant is defined as a preprocessor macro (`#define`) as follows:

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
#define CONNECTION_TIMEOUT 3
#endif
```

The reason why I use `#ifndef` and `#endif` here is because I want this macro to be configurable at compile time, that is, through the `./configure` script. In order to allow this, I added an switch in my `configure.ac` file:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([timeout], [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-timeout], [...])])
AS_IF([test "x$with-timeout" != "x"],
    [AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([CONNECTION_TIMEOUT], ["$with-timeout"], ["..."])]
)
```

Thanks to this, users can compile the application with a custom timeout value:

```
./configure --with-timeout=1
```

Thing is, when I do this, my macro is set to `"1"`, instead of `1`. Because of this, when I try to manipulate it...

```
int timeout = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
```

... pointer `(char*)` to integer `(int)`, without a cast. Quite expectable.

How can I get `autoconf` to set my macro to an integer value, without quotes? I have tried using single quotes, and `AC_DEFINE` but I can't get it to the right value...

Comment: Did you try just using `[$with-timeout]` instead of `["$with-timeout"]` ?

Comment: Yes. My macro is set to `"-timeout"` (`$with` is empty, `-timeout` is taken as a string).

Comment: Generally speaking, `AC_ARG_WITH` is used for external packages, you might want to take a look at `AC_ARG_VAR` in the first place. Using `AC_ARG_WITH` allows the use of `--without-timeout` for example. Then, just use a variable name without dashes and you can drop the quotes like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to dereference the wrong shell variable.  Autoconf presents the value of the --with-timeout argument as `$with_timeout` (note: underscore instead of hyphen).  The expression `$with-timeout` is a concatentation of the likely-uninitialized variable `$with` and the literal string `-timeout`.

In other words, use

```
AC_DEFINE([CONNECTION_TIMEOUT], [$with_timeout])
```

Comment: And... compilation was a success, thank you! I used `AF_DEFINE_UNQUOTED` though, otherwise, I get to dereferencing at all.